# thread-safe collection for store and forward

Tags: java, collections, concurrency

Here is the situation that we have to develop for.
We would have a swarm of ids getting inserted continuously to a collection by a single writer.
The intention is to alert the clients about these particular ids.
For this purpose, a schedule thread would traverse through this collection,collate the ids ,and 'reset' the collection to empty thereafter.
I intended to use ConcurrentLinkedQueue for this.
Although this would make it thread-safe;there is a possibility of 'reset' clearing off some ids that have not been alerted yet.
What would be the best way to go about this?

Answer (score 0):

Your collator thread should remove each entry from the queue as it processes it.  If you do it this way, there is no need to reset the queue, and your problem with lost notifications does not arise.

(If this doesn't make sense to you, there is most likely something that you are not explaining clearly.  Try adding some example code ...)

Answer (score 0):

Possibility of 'reset' clearing off some ids is only the problem, so for that what you can do is:

In schedule thread,

First get the **current** size/no of ids present in the queue at that particular 
time in a local variable "**size**" because it will change as new element get inserted.
Then iterate on ConcurrentLinkedQueue till that **size**,
while iterating remove/poll the elements from ConcurrentLinkedQueue to collect the ids.

In this way you need not to reset the ConcurrentLinkedQueue.

Answer (score 0):

The simpler you can keep this, the less there will be to go wrong.

I'd create a container to manage your collection of ids, exposing only the two operations you need.

Your write thread needs to add entries to the collection, and your schedule thread needs to pick them up in batches. A copy-on-read strategy would only require a few lines:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

public class IdList<T> {
    private ArrayList<T> entries = new ArrayList<>();

    /**
     * Add a notification ID to the collection.
     */
    public synchronized void add(T entry) {
        entries.add(entry);
    }

    /**
     * Remove the next batch of notification IDs from the collection.
     */
    public synchronized List<T> drain() {
        ArrayList<T> current = entries;
        entries = new ArrayList<>();
        return current;
    }
}
```